# Sharing the same settings.xml maven configuration for the whole team

Tags: maven, configuration-management

We have a very big maven configuration with very many repositories, plugin repositories, and various other things.

We always end up having to manually copy/paste the same file to other team members, and then replace the username and password.

I was curious if anyone is aware of an automated solution for sharing the settings.xml file ?

Something that will pull the configuration or part of the configuration from git ?

If I had to write it myself I would probably use a script and git, to pull changes, do replacements, and replace the current settings file.

But it's better to see if someone has already made this.

We also have a different proxy username and password for each user.
We use both nexus, and also a proxy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tomtit](https://github.com/melezhik/Tomtit) is good with that type of tasks, just include this small helper into your scm:

**.tom/mvn-settings.pl6**

```
#!perl6

my $user = prompt "username ";
my $password = prompt "password ";

directory '/tmp/mvn';

# load settings template from other repository

git-scm 'https://scm/repo/mvn-files', %( to => '/tmp/mvn' );

template-create 'settings.xml', %(
  source => ( slurp '/tmp/mvn/settings.tmpl' ),
  mode => '644',
  variables => %(
    user => $user,
    password => $password
  ),
);
```

The run it:

```
tom mvn-settings
```

Answer (score 0):

We use a Nexus, which proxies all the desired repositories. This means that the repositories and plugin repositories section in the `settings.xml` have only one entry each (pointing to the public group).

Furthermore, adding/changing repositories can be done by the Nexus admin, and is propagated automatically to everyone (about 140 developers) using the standard `settings.xml`.

You furthermore gain the caching advantage because the artifacts are downloaded only once from the internet and cached by Nexus, which can speed up your builds.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's another department that has nexus admin account. 
And there are many nexus repositories all managed by different department. One department per repository actually.

Comment: But couldn't you just set up your own Nexus in your department/group, that proxies all the Nexus that you need? Or are you not allowed to run a server?

Comment: Nope.. we are forbidden. We deploy on corporate servers controlled by a central department and all our infrastructure is also controlled.

Comment: Then maybe the "central department" could set up a dedicated Nexus server for your developer group? I know that these organisational things are sometimes hard, but trying to circumvent the situation by constructing a home-baked settings.xml sharing is also not ideal.